# how to parse json object inside array inside object in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

How can I JSON object inside an array in swift4? How ca I get the response for this JSON in swift4? I am printing the location but its's getting `nil`.

Here its my JSON data:

```
{
    "Details": [{
        "phone": 
        "id":
    }],
    "address": [{
       "location": "some location"
   }]
}

 do {
     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]

     let location = json["location"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
     print(location)

 } catch {         
     print("error")       
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json["location"]` doesn't exist and therefore is not an array. Location is inside the address array.

try

```
if let addressArray = json["address"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    let address = addressArray.first
    let location = address?["location'] as? String
    print(location)
}
```

NOTES

1. In your JSON location was missing any value i.e `"location":` I added a String
2. it's better to use the Codable protocol in Swift 4

Comment: why u wrote addressArray.first what is first?

Comment: Square bracket `[]` in JSON is an array/list. so addressArray is a list of addresses, `.first` gets the first item in the list

Comment: so i want the "phone" soo i need to call  Details.second?

Comment: Yes maybe, you need to check that the second item in the list is definitely the phone number